# Seating optimization on a complement network

Tags: python, networkx

I'm looking to perform a seating optimization paradigm but unlike traditional problems where you want to group like people together, I'd like to do this based on people who don't know each other. for example, if we have 100 people and know the both the in and out degrees of everyone, as well as the edge weights (edge weights = how well they know each other).

I've been thinking about using the complement network (`nx.complement(g)`) then using community detection. The problem with this is that we need to be able to specify the number of communities and the maximum number of people per community. In addition, I'd also need to be able to do this 3-4 times to get multiple rounds of tables (think 4 different breakout sessions, each where nobody knows each other, and there's minimal overlap between breakout session).

What other possible solutions are there where we can minimize the total number of connections per table given the constraints listed above?

Comment: Nice problem. Do you assume you know the number of required communities ('tables') in the seating arrangement)? If not, how would you express the output?

Comment: Ah yes. we would know the total number of people, and the number per table. So from there we can say how many tables we would need. Ideal output would be a list of people and their table number they were assigned to for all 4 events.

Comment: What is the expectation of the density of the input graph? 5%, 10%, 50%?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on the expectations of the density, I think it could be as high as 50%.